# XPath get all values of specific attribute in the whole document

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to XPath and couldn't find the the way of how can I get all possible values of specific attribute in the whole XML file.

I have a situation that almost every tag in a given file has optional `lang` attribute and I need to get all possible values of `lang` attribute from the whole file.

Would appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get all possible `lang` values you can try

```
//*/@lang
```

If you want list of unique values only:

```
distinct-values(//*/@lang)  # For XPath 2.0
```

or

```
//*[not(@lang = preceding::*/@lang)]/@lang  # For XPath 1.0
```

Comment: `//@lang` is effectively the same but shorter than `//*/@lang`.